# Error: "GRIB_API ERROR : Unknown stepType=[7] timeRangeIndicator=[7] " using eccodes

Tags: python, weather, grib, pygrib, grib-api

I'm working with grib files from Nasa - files from NLDAS Noah model.

I'm using pygrib and grib tools (both based on eccodes engine).

When I try to get data from the file (using grib_get_data/grib_ls) or using readline (with pygrib)
I get the same error:

**when using grib_ls:**

```
GRIB_API ERROR   :  Unknown stepType=[7] timeRangeIndicator=[7]
1            kwbc         surface      0            20010101     Function not yet implemented stepRange
```

**When using pygrib:**

```
ECCODES ERROR   :  Unknown stepType=[7] timeRangeIndicator=[7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pygrib.pyx", line 911, in pygrib.gribmessage.__repr__
  File "pygrib.pyx", line 1268, in pygrib.gribmessage.__getitem__
RuntimeError: b'Function not yet implemented'
```

I have tried to work with several different files from this model but same result.

This is the link to the NLDAS Noah model dataset:
https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/NLDAS_NOAH0125_H_002/summary?keywords=NLDAS_NOAH0125_H

I need the data from this specific model, any suggestions what can I do?
or did I miss something?

Comment: My recommendation is to use xarray+ cfgrib instead of pygrib. Easier to install and easier to handle because you receive data as xarray.Dataset .

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out(: